# How to store data from database to a variable in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

How to store data from database in a variable in `PHP`. because the data I want to use that many times in my project. like:

```
foreach ($data as $value) 
{
    $Table = '
        <TR>
            <TD>' . $value['name'] . '</td>
            <TD>' . $value['date'] . '</TD>
            <TD>' . $value['time'] . '</TD>
        </TR>';
}

echo $Table;
```

Now I am getting only the first row of the result, it's not looping proprly. Help me to fix this.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: use `$Table+=` ... instead of `$Table=` because that overwrites the value again and again

Comment: @Alexander: I think you mean `$Table .=` - this is concatenation, not addition.

Comment: @halfer yes of course

Comment: For the benefit of future readers (and the OP) all five answers (at the time of this comment) trap blocks of HTML inside HTML strings, where they cannot be tag-matched nor colourised by your IDE. This isn't particularly elegant, and creates lots of room for improvement. PHP allows you to snap in and out of HTML mode, so why not use it? Keep your PHP snippets as short as possible, and do the rest in HTML outside of PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($data as $value){
    $table.='

      <tr>

           <td>'.$value['name'].'</td>
           <td>'.$value['date'].'</td>
            <td>'.$value['time'].'</td>

      </tr>';
}
echo $table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look to below code, I have made some modification and hope this will help you.

```
$Table = "<table name='data' id='data'>"; 

    foreach ($data as $value){

     $Table .= "<tr>";
     $Table .= "<td>".$value['name']."</td>";
     $Table .= "<td>".$value['date']."</td>";
     $Table .= "<td>".$value['time']."</td>";
     $Table .= "</tr>";

                                 }
$Table .= "</table>";
    echo $Table;
```